# Nintex Reusable Workflow - How to add data when associating the workflow to a list

Tags: nintex-workflow

Please can you explain to me how you can pass start data to a nintex reusable workflow, when you first associate it to a list.

I have created a reusable workflow which has to move a document from source library to a destination library. The problem i have at the moment, is how to give my workflow the names of my source and destination libraries, when i associate the workflow to a list.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this directly. But I have an idea that could help you:

1. Create another list with 2 columns (e.g. Source and Destination)
2. Create a new workflow and associate it to this list. In "Workflow Settings", set "Start when items are created" to Yes.
3. In your reusable workflow, add two new variables (e.g. "Source" and "Destination") checking "Show on start form" option.
4. In your new workflow, add a "Start Workflow" action and set these variable values.

I hope it helps! :)